# Encrypting config transforms

Tags: c#, encryption, web-config, app-config

I need to encrypt various sections of many app and web.config files. I've written a small utility that looks something like this:

```
public class ConfigData
{
    public string Path { get; private set; }
    public IList<string> Sections { get; private set; }

    public ConfigData(string path, IEnumerable<string> sections)
    {
        Path = path;
        Sections = new List<string>(sections);
    }
} 

private static void EncryptDecrypt(ConfigData configData)
{
    var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = configData.Path };
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    var changesMade = false;
    foreach (var sectionName in configData.Sections)
    {
        var section = config.GetSection(sectionName);
        if (section != null && !section.ElementInformation.IsLocked)
        {
            if (section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
            {
                section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
            }
            else
            {
                section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("MyConfigurationProvider");
            }

            section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
            changesMade = true;
        }
    }

    if (changesMade)
    {
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
    }
}
```

This works for standard web and app.configs, but when I run it on a config transform, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connection1" connectionString="myConnectionString" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I get an exception at `var section = config.GetSection(sectionName);` that says `'xdt' is an undeclared prefix`. xdt is declared, so I'm not sure how to proceed. How can I encrypt config transforms?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, I ended up writing a custom transform parser/encryptor that worked for what we needed